# Computing the elliptic integral $\int \frac{1}{x \sqrt{f+\frac{a}{x^3}-\frac{k}{x^2}}} \, dx$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I don't know how to solve this with or without Rubi?!!

```
 Get["Rubi`"]
 Assuming[f > 0 && k > 0, Int[1/(x*Sqrt[f + a*x^-3 - k*x^-2]), {x,1,u}]]
```

Comment: Are there any assumptions on `a`?

Comment: Rubi indifinite integration does not use assumptions. They have no effect. It is all just rules based.

Comment: @Nasser yes, I meant in order to input assumptions into mathematica. It is stated `with or without Rubi`. Also, to the author of the OP, perhaps you can change the title to "Computing elliptic integrals" or something to that effect

Comment: @bmf I was actually just replying to the OP, since they used assumptions with Rubi.

Comment: @Nasser oops. Sorry then :)

Comment: This gives a result: `Integrate[1/(x*Sqrt[f + a*x^-3 - k*x^-2]), x]`

Comment: As @DanielLichtblau points out, current versions handle the integral. What version are you using?

Comment: yes a>0 as well.

Comment: I'm using Mathematica 13

Comment: Me too. You do not get a result from `Integrate`?

Comment: In the future it would be good to use @ and start typing a user's name, so they can receive a notification that you answered to their comment. Also, you changed the statement of the problem and now you want a definite integral. Q: what is `u`. Finally, since you use `V13` am I right to assume that you want an explicit result and nothing with `Root` in it?

Comment: @FelipeDura it's difficult to keep up with what you want to do, but in a comment under an answer that is not an answer you asked if you can compute numerically. Yes, you can. You just need to feed into Mathematica numerical values. For instance, this `With[{f = 1, a = 0.1, k = 1/2, u = 10}, NIntegrate[1/(x*Sqrt[f + a*x^-3 - k*x^-2]), {x, 1, u}]]` gives `2.43135`.

Comment: @FelipeDura also try this `integral[f_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, k_?NumericQ, u_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[1/(x*Sqrt[f + a*x^-3 - k*x^-2]), {x, 1, u}]` and then `Manipulate[ListPlot[Table[integral[f, a, k, u], {u, 1, 100, 1}], PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 5}}, ImageSize -> Large], {f, 1, 3}, {a, 1, 3}, {k, 1, 3}`. You should get [`this`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBZrN.gif)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to see if MathJax could handle rendering the result: Daniel Lichtbau points out that directly calling `Integrate` works.

```
TeXForm@Simplify@ToRadicals@Integrate[1/(x Sqrt[f+a x^-3-k x^-2]),x]
```

gives this when pasted.

$$\frac{2 \left(\sqrt[3]{2} \left(-i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(\sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-9 a f^2\right)^{2/3}-2 \sqrt[3]{3} \left(i+\sqrt{3}\right) f k\right) \left(2 \sqrt[3]{2} 3^{2/3} f k-6 f \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-9 a f^2} x+\sqrt[3]{3} \left(2 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-18 a f^2\right)^{2/3}\right)^2 \sqrt{\frac{f^2 \left(\sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-9 a f^2\right)^{7/3} x \left(-108 i \sqrt{3} a^2 f^3+3 a \left(36 k x f^2+\sqrt[6]{3} \sqrt[3]{2 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-18 a f^2} \left(2 \sqrt[3]{2} \sqrt[6]{3} \left(3+i \sqrt{3}\right) k+3 \left(i+\sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-9 a f^2} x\right) f+12 i \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}\right) f-\sqrt[6]{3} \left(2 \left(2^{2/3} \sqrt[6]{3} \left(3-i \sqrt{3}\right) k^2 \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-9 a f^2} x-8 i \sqrt[3]{3} k^3\right) f^2+4 \left(\sqrt[3]{2} \left(-i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(\sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-9 a f^2\right)^{2/3} k^2+3 \sqrt[3]{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)} x k\right) f+\sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)} \sqrt[3]{2 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-18 a f^2} \left(2 \sqrt[3]{2} \sqrt[6]{3} \left(i+\sqrt{3}\right) k+\left(3+i \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-9 a f^2} x\right)\right)\right)}{\left(-9 i \sqrt[3]{2} \left(-i+\sqrt{3}\right) a f^2+2 \left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right) k \sqrt[3]{3 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-27 a f^2} f+\sqrt[3]{2} \left(3 i+\sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}\right)^2 \left(-9 a \left(2^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{3 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-27 a f^2}-6 f x\right) f^2-6 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)} x f+2 \sqrt[3]{2} k \left(3 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-27 a f^2\right)^{2/3} f+2^{2/3} 3^{5/6} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)} \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-9 a f^2}\right)^2}} \sqrt{\frac{\left(\sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-9 a f^2\right)^{2/3} \left(2 k \sqrt[3]{6 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-54 a f^2} \left(\sqrt[3]{2} \left(-i+\sqrt{3}\right) k-2 i \sqrt[3]{3 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-27 a f^2} x\right) f^2+3 i a \left(6 f \left(2 k+2^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{3 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-27 a f^2} x\right)+\sqrt[3]{2} \sqrt[6]{3} \left(-3 i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(\sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-9 a f^2\right)^{2/3}\right) f^2-2 i \sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)} \left(2 k+2^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{3 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-27 a f^2} x\right) f-\sqrt[3]{2} \sqrt[6]{3} \left(i+\sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)} \left(\sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-9 a f^2\right)^{2/3}\right)}{\left(9 \sqrt[3]{2} \left(i+\sqrt{3}\right) a f^2+2 \left(-i+\sqrt{3}\right) k \sqrt[3]{3 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-27 a f^2} f+\sqrt[3]{2} \left(-3-i \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}\right) \left(-9 a \left(2^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{3 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-27 a f^2}-6 f x\right) f^2-6 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)} x f+2 \sqrt[3]{2} k \left(3 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-27 a f^2\right)^{2/3} f+2^{2/3} 3^{5/6} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)} \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-9 a f^2}\right)}} \left(F\left(\sin ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{6} \sqrt{\frac{f \left(2 \left(3 i+\sqrt{3}\right) f k \sqrt[3]{3 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-27 a f^2}-\sqrt[3]{2} \left(-3 i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(\sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-9 a f^2\right)\right) x}{\left(\sqrt[3]{2} \left(-i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(\sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-9 a f^2\right)^{2/3}-2 \sqrt[3]{3} \left(i+\sqrt{3}\right) f k\right) \left(2 \sqrt[3]{2} 3^{2/3} f k-6 f \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-9 a f^2} x+\sqrt[3]{3} \left(2 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-18 a f^2\right)^{2/3}\right)}}\right)|\frac{\left(\sqrt[3]{2} \left(-i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(\sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-9 a f^2\right)^{2/3}-2 \sqrt[3]{3} \left(i+\sqrt{3}\right) f k\right) \left(\sqrt[3]{2} \left(3 i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(\sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-9 a f^2\right)^{2/3}-2 \sqrt[3]{3} \left(-3 i+\sqrt{3}\right) f k\right)}{\left(\sqrt[3]{2} \left(i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(\sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-9 a f^2\right)^{2/3}-2 \sqrt[3]{3} \left(-i+\sqrt{3}\right) f k\right) \left(\sqrt[3]{2} \left(-3 i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(\sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-9 a f^2\right)^{2/3}-2 \sqrt[3]{3} \left(3 i+\sqrt{3}\right) f k\right)}\right)-\Pi \left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{2} \left(-i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(\sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-9 a f^2\right)^{2/3}-2 \sqrt[3]{3} \left(i+\sqrt{3}\right) f k}{\sqrt[3]{2} \left(-3 i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(\sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-9 a f^2\right)^{2/3}-2 \sqrt[3]{3} \left(3 i+\sqrt{3}\right) f k};\sin ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{6} \sqrt{\frac{f \left(2 \left(3 i+\sqrt{3}\right) f k \sqrt[3]{3 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-27 a f^2}-\sqrt[3]{2} \left(-3 i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(\sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-9 a f^2\right)\right) x}{\left(\sqrt[3]{2} \left(-i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(\sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-9 a f^2\right)^{2/3}-2 \sqrt[3]{3} \left(i+\sqrt{3}\right) f k\right) \left(2 \sqrt[3]{2} 3^{2/3} f k-6 f \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-9 a f^2} x+\sqrt[3]{3} \left(2 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-18 a f^2\right)^{2/3}\right)}}\right)|\frac{\left(\sqrt[3]{2} \left(-i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(\sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-9 a f^2\right)^{2/3}-2 \sqrt[3]{3} \left(i+\sqrt{3}\right) f k\right) \left(\sqrt[3]{2} \left(3 i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(\sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-9 a f^2\right)^{2/3}-2 \sqrt[3]{3} \left(-3 i+\sqrt{3}\right) f k\right)}{\left(\sqrt[3]{2} \left(i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(\sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-9 a f^2\right)^{2/3}-2 \sqrt[3]{3} \left(-i+\sqrt{3}\right) f k\right) \left(\sqrt[3]{2} \left(-3 i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(\sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-9 a f^2\right)^{2/3}-2 \sqrt[3]{3} \left(3 i+\sqrt{3}\right) f k\right)}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{3} f^2 \left(\sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-9 a f^2\right)^{2/3} \left(2 \sqrt[3]{3} \left(3 i+\sqrt{3}\right) f k-\sqrt[3]{2} \left(-3 i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(\sqrt{3} \sqrt{f^3 \left(27 a^2 f-4 k^3\right)}-9 a f^2\right)^{2/3}\right) x^2 \sqrt{f+\frac{a-k x}{x^3}}}$$

This expression has an evaluation of `EllipticF`, $F$, and `EllipticPi`, $\Pi$.  Both of them have some weird TeX rendering with $|$ and $;$.  If this is buggy or makes the page slow, I'll remove it and link to an image instead.

I'd like to verify the Mathematica result by taking a derivative, but

```
Simplify@D[Simplify@ToRadicals@Integrate[1/(x Sqrt[f+a x^-3-k x^-2]),x],x]
```

doesn't evaluate for me.

Interestingly, calling `Integrate[1/(x Sqrt[f+a x^-3-k x^-2]),{x,1,u}]` takes a very long time to evaluate (I don't know if it completes).  To evaluate the result another way, you can do something like

```
Remove@result
result[x_] = Integrate[1/(x Sqrt[f+a x^-3-k x^-2]),x]
```

once, then use it

```
N[result[99]-result[1]/.{k->1,f->2,a->2}]
```

with whatever values you like, or for plotting.

Answer (score -2):

```
 (2 (EllipticF[ArcSin[Sqrt[(x (-Root[a - k #1 + f #1^3 &, 1] + 
      Root[a - k #1 + f #1^3 &, 3]))/((x - 
      Root[a - k #1 + f #1^3 &, 1]) Root[a - k #1 + f #1^3 &, 
     3])]], ((Root[a - k #1 + f #1^3 &, 1] - 
     Root[a - k #1 + f #1^3 &, 2]) Root[a - k #1 + f #1^3 &, 3])/(
  Root[a - k #1 + f #1^3 &, 2] (Root[a - k #1 + f #1^3 &, 1] - 
     Root[a - k #1 + f #1^3 &, 3]))] - 
  EllipticPi[Root[a - k #1 + f #1^3 &, 3]/(-Root[a - k #1 + f #1^3 &, 1] 
 + Root[a - k #1 + f #1^3 &, 3]), 
  ArcSin[Sqrt[(x (-Root[a - k #1 + f #1^3 &, 1] + 
      Root[a - k #1 + f #1^3 &, 3]))/((x - 
      Root[a - k #1 + f #1^3 &, 1]) Root[a - k #1 + f #1^3 &, 
     3])]], ((Root[a - k #1 + f #1^3 &, 1] - 
     Root[a - k #1 + f #1^3 &, 2]) Root[a - k #1 + f #1^3 &, 3])/(
  Root[a - k #1 + f #1^3 &, 
    2] (Root[a - k #1 + f #1^3 &, 1] - 
      Root[a - k #1 + f #1^3 &, 3]))]) (x - Root[a - k #1 + f #1^3 &, 1])^2 Sqrt[(
      Root[a - k #1 + f #1^3 &, 1] (x - Root[a - k #1 + f #1^3 &, 2]))/((x - Root[a - k #1 + f #1^3 &, 1]) Root[a - k #1 + f #1^3 &, 2])]Root[a - k #1 + f #1^3 &, 3] \[Sqrt]((x Root[a - k #1 + f #1^3 &, 
     1] (x - Root[a - k #1 + f #1^3 &, 3]) (-Root[a - k #1 + f #1^3 &, 1] + Root[a - k #1 + f #1^3 &, 3]))/((x - Root[a - k #1 + f #1^3 &, 1])^2 Root[a - k #1 + f #1^3 &, 3]^2)))/(x^2 Sqrt[f + (a - k x)/x^3] (Root[a - k #1 + f #1^3 &, 1] - Root[a - k #1 + f #1^3 &, 3]))
```

Comment: The op has changed the question again.  It is now definite integral. so the answer should not have $x$ in it. And it would be better to have the answer be self contained. i.e. including the input and output and not just the output just to make it more clear.

Comment: Can anyone make more simple this solution??
Integrate[1/(x*Sqrt[f + a*x^-3 - k*x^-2]), x]

Comment: @FelipeDura it does not look like the indefinite integral can be expressed in terms of elementary functions, which is what you seem to want. Mathematica's result using Elliptic functions could be the best one can hope for. I tried this in other CAS systems, and non of them solved it, other than Maple, which gives similar result to Mathematica's.

Comment: What about if we solve this under some limit like x->infinity and see which terms play important rule!!

Comment: @FelipeDura well, we cannot be guessing that you wanted these things, I hope you can understand that. `AsymptoticIntegrate` is the command you want by the way

Answer (score -3):

AsymptoticIntegrate[1/(x*Sqrt[f + a*x^-3 - k*x^-2]), x, x -> 1]

Comment: This does not appear to answer the question.

Comment: Is there anyway to compute like numerical or parametric integral?!!

Comment: @bbgodfrey I tried to flag this as not-being-an-answer to no avail.